# How tornado future works?

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, tornado

> 1. I am writing a web server in tornado and I wanted to know how does tornado.concurrent.Future works? I have seen the example of
>      AsyncHTTPClient() but if I want to make my own function which has some
>      some IO operations to perform like get the values from memcache how do
>      I make it to work asynchronously?
> 2. When I use websocket.WebSocketHandler is the function call write_message() blocking the server? My code is like this below:

```
 `class SocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):  
     @gen.coroutine     
     def getMemcVal(self):      
         self.write_message("some test value")`
```

> 3. How does the Future differ from the callbacks?

Comment: For your second question, "Yes". For your first question, you need to first learn how to program asynchronously.

Comment: What if I just do `yield self.write_message("some test value")` will that work good?

Comment: No, it won't make that work better even a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example about how `async & await` works:

```
# python
async def example():
    response = await request.get(“http://www.google.com”)
    result = await response.read()
    print(result)
```

equals to `callback` in nodejs:

```
function example() {
    request.get(“http://www.google.com”, function (response){
        response.read(function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        })
    })  
}
```

## update

So what is `Future`? It is an abstract concept. You think an asynchronous function as an object, and then you think `event loop` is scheduling multiple objects like scheduling multiple threads by recognizing `await`.

But what is real inside it? Just the same as `callback`. It's just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: `result = await response.read()` is this not same as sending the callback?

Comment: @aja It is the same.

Comment: But what advantage do I get if I use Future?

Comment: @aja You can write asynchronous code just as writing synchronous code. You don't need to write a lot of callbacks, your code becomes clearer and process control becomes very easy.

Comment: Thanks for the help +1